# I can't find out how to get operators to work the way I want them to

Tags: javascript, variables, operators

I have a bit of code in an if statement that doesn't consistently work. I can't tell why.

This is my code:

```js
CNSinsertG.CNlogo = true;
CNskipG = true;
a = CNSinsertG.CNlogo == true ||
    CNSinsertG.CNlogo == undefined ||
   (CNSinsertG.CNlogo == null && CNskipG == false) ||
    CNskipG == undefined ||
    CNskipG == null;
```

I was hoping for a to equal false because CNskipG==true, but it equals true.

Comment: Try this, easier to read and understand and is using === which does not give surprising results when something is truthy or falsy. Move the most likely tests to the top: `let logo = CNSinsertG.CNlogo;
a = ( logo === true ||  logo === undefined || CNskipG === undefined || (logo === null && CNskipG === false) || CNskipG === null);` You can remove mosts of the tests if you yourself set the variables to either true or false. I assume you do not otherwise needless tests for undefined and null